# Probability of Group Standings vs. Randomized Standings

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

This question concerns MLB baseball standings.

There are 6 divisions with 5 teams each for 30 total teams.  Currently one division has three of the four best records.  What are the odds that this occurs?

I'm thinking to solve this you would use some nCr or nPr statistic functions, but I'm not sure exactly how to solve it.

http://espn.go.com/mlb/standings/_/group/overall

Comment: I have selected the answer below, thank you.  That was what I was looking for, although I realize the actual answer is more complicated since teams within a division play each other more than non-divisional rivals.

Comment: Also, can people explain why this was down-voted? I don't have a problem with that, more so that people would down vote my first question with no recommendation for improvement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(As DaleM points out below, this runs under loose assumptions.  Here, I assumed that the order of the thirty teams was (uniformly) randomly picked; this is not the case in reality as two teams are more likely to play each other if they're within the same division than if they're in different divisions.  In order to get a more close answer, we need to know more/make more assumptions about the teams themselves, and the ratio of games played within the division vs. out of the division.)

---

You're right that this does concern $nCr$; a lot of the time in math, we typically use the notation $\binom{n}{r}$ instead.  Recall that $\binom{n}{r}$ is the total number of ways to pick $r$ things from a set of $n$ total things.  The total number of ways to pick $4$ teams from a total of $30$ is $\binom{30}{4}$.  The number of ways to pick four teams such that exactly three come from the same division is as follows:

- We have to pick which division it comes from.
- We have to pick the $3$ teams from that division.
- We have to pick the remaining team from the other divisions.

This total number is $6\cdot\binom{5}{3}\cdot \binom{25}{1}$.  Thus, the probability is $$ \frac{6\cdot\binom{5}{3}\cdot \binom{25}{1}}{\binom{30}{4}}  \approx .0547.$$

So the probability of this occurring is about $5.5\%$.

Comment: Except ... the standings of the teams are not independent.

Comment: @DaleM, That's not necessarily relevant; if we randomly order the teams, and then pick the top $4$, that's the same as randomly picking a subset of $4$ teams.

Comment: It probably is relevant, baseball is a zero-sum game and teams in the same division play each other *more* than they play teams in the other divisions. Overall this will reduce the likelihood of the occurrence.

Comment: @DaleM, Ah, I understand.  I'm fairly sports-illiterate and didn't even think about ratio of games played within a division/out of the division.  That'll definitely make a difference, then.  Thanks for pointing that out!